# BLS credentials

Tags: coinbase, withdrawal, shapella

Changing the wallet address at the BLS, will that be possible at some point?

I submitted my Coinbase address to the BLS credentials and now I'm at a loss. Is everything gone now?
Are there developers at ETH who are working on this topic, or are there other forums where the topic is already being discussed?

THX

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking. Are you running your own validator? Have you checked ethereum website FAQ https://launchpad.ethereum.org/en/withdrawals?